# How do I replicate and center an object in an Excel worksheet using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA that takes the contents of a few different worksheets, and prints them to PDF.  I'm trying to add a watermark type effect to each page that gets printed.  However, not every page will receive the same watermark.  I have a textbox that will correctly get updated as the VBA is running, and will always have what I want my "watermark" to be.  I've gotten to the point where I can copy the textbox and paste it in a specific location, but I need to be able to paste it in multiple locations, which will not always be the same.  I'm looking for each page to contain the "watermark" and for it to be centered (and potentially resized down to the dimensions of the page in a case where the watermark is larger than the page).  Additionally, the number of pages added to the PDF by the sheet is variable, but all pages should always receive the "watermark".  I have virtually no background in VBA.  The below code was produced by recording a macro.

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 3")).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
Range("C16").SelectActiveSheet.Paste
```

I need the paste location to be dynamic and centered in the middle of the printed page.  I also need the image to appear on each printed page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  One of the things the existing VBA does is print all the pages on the worksheet to PDF.  It then changes values of the pages, and prints them to PDF as well.  I need the watermark to update when the values do, which is currently working.  The problem I am having is that when the values change, the number of rows change, and so does the page count.  If I had a static page count I would just add the watermark (which is already updating as needed) everywhere it's supposed to be.

Comment: Start by following this: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/19/insert-watermark-excel-worksheets/ and use the macro recorder to record your actions. It will give you more code that add to what you have currently.

Comment: Hey braX, thanks for the response.  I took a look at that link, and it's not helping my solve the specific problem I am running into here.  The watermark I want to use is not an image file outside of the spreadsheet, it's a textbox in the spreadsheet.  Also, using the header/footer option doesn't seem to be flexible enough for what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: What you want to do may not be possible. I guess you will have to wait and see what others say.

Comment: Are there any hidden rows, hidden columns, or print areas?  Are all the row heights  and Column Widths the same?

Comment: There are no hidden rows or columns or print areas.  Every row has the same height.  Not all columns have the same width.